# New to Amateur Radio

Tags: electronics

I'm new to radio, and I'm trying to get into the electronics aspect of it.

I was wondering if it was at all possible to build your own transmitter, receiver, etc. (basic radio components) as good beginner project.

I've searched the Internet for tutorials, but the links have either made it seem too complicated or they aren't actually simple.

Anyways, if you all could refer me to some beginner material, that would be great.

By the way, if my question is too vague, let me know and I can edit it. I'm new to the whole Stack Exchange too.

Comment: When I think of kits, two companies come to mind:  http://www.elecraft.com/ where most everything is a kit ad you pay more for fully or partially assembled versions,  and http://www.tentec.com which sells a few kits among many other products.  On the digital side there's http://tapr.org  It is also possible to look through old ARRL Handbooks and QST magazine and build kits from discrete components.  Unfortunately, a lot of magazine article projects used a printed circuit board that might have been available only for a short time.

Answer (score 3):

Most hams don't build their own transmitters and receivers, more's the shame.  But it is quite possible, depending on your skill level and determination.

The simplest rigs (the place to start first, of course) are generally what are called "QRP" (low power) radios.  You can find a lot of information through the ARRL web: http://www.arrl.org/qrp-low-power-operating and also at the ARRL bookstore.  You can buy QRP radios in kit form, too.

If you haven't looked into ARRL, I recommend you check out http://www.arrl.org/what-is-ham-radio, and consider joining the League.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly reccomend reading the book [Crystal Sets to Sideband](http://www.qsl.net/k0iye/) by Frank Harris K0IYE.

This book should get you started in the process of homebrewing radios and starts out with a very basic easy to build circuits to complicated radio projects up to the present stuff he is working on.

I live not to far, and met him. His entire station is homebrew including a 10-80 meter SSB/CW/AM transceiver, power supply, morse key, antenna tuner, antenna etc. It was quite amazing!

Below is an image of his homebrew radios:

[image]